# Changing to Date Format in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data column called month which I want to convert into date format

In the spreadsheet, it's of the form Mar-07

But when I try to convert it in R using:

```
mydata$month<-as.Date(mydata$month, format = "%b-%y")
```

I get NAs

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: date format requires day, month and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zoo` package has a class, `yearmon`, which can represent monthly data. There is an `as.Date` method for this class.

```
library(zoo)

ym <- as.yearmon("Mar-07", "%b-%y")
str(ym)
# Class 'yearmon'  num 2007
```

Convert `yearmon` object to class `Date`:

```
date <- as.Date(ym)
date
# [1] "2007-03-01"

str(date)
# Date[1:1], format: "2007-03-01"
```

The `frac` argument can be used to indicate a fraction of the month. The default `frac` is 0, i.e. first day in month, as above.

```
as.Date(ym, frac = 0.5)
# [1] "2007-03-16"

as.Date(ym, frac = 1)
# [1] "2007-03-31"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround:

```
dts <- paste(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), "07", sep="-")
# [1] "Jan-07" "Feb-07" "Mar-07"
as.Date(paste0("1", dts), format = "%d%b-%y")
# [1] "2007-01-01" "2007-02-01" "2007-03-01"
```